# By changing the package name, what consequences will occur?

Tags: android, package

I'm doing a project with com.example.something. I bought a website recently, is it far to change the package name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unles you have not released your app on Google Play Store, there is no any issue if you change the package name.

To change the package name you can follow this link:
[Android Studio Rename Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package)

**Things That Cannot Change:**

The most obvious and visible of these is the “manifest package name,” the unique name you give to your application in its AndroidManifest.xml. The name uses a Java-language-style naming convention, with Internet domain ownership helping to avoid name collisions. For example, since Google owns the domain “google.com”, the manifest package names of all of our applications should start with “com.google.” It’s important for developers to follow this convention in order to avoid conflicts with other developers.

Once you publish your application under its manifest package name, this is the unique identity of the application forever more. Switching to a different name results in an entirely new application, one that can’t be installed as an update to the existing application.